# Plotting a function of $x$ for various values of parameter $a$

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I need to plot the function `a^x` where the parameter `a` takes on values  `a={2,1,1/2,e}`. So far I have tried:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{f[_x],a^x},{x,0,10}],{a,1,1}]
```

I mean technically it works but it doesn't look good.

I would appreciate it if I can get help with this plot with/without the use of `Manipulate`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 4):

Without `Manipulate` try

```
Plot[Table[a^x, {a, {2, 1, 1/2, E}}], {x, 0, 10},PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) provides greater flexibility by enabling control over each individual curve.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

bases = {1/2, 1, 2, E, 3};

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@bases];

Manipulate[
 sel = ReverseSortBy[sel, N];
 Plot[Evaluate[bases[[sel]]^x], {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> colors[[sel]],
  PlotRange -> {-0.1, 3.1},
  PlotLegends -> (bases[[sel]])^x],
 {{sel, Range[Length@bases], "selection"},
  Thread[Range[Length@bases] -> bases],
  ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As f[x] is not defined, I assume f[x]=Exp[x]:

```
f[x_] = Exp[x];
Manipulate[Plot[{f[x], a^x}, {x, 0, 1}], {a, {2, 1, 1/2, e}}]
```

[image]